# Ignore NA's in sapply function

Tags: function, r, sapply

I am using R and have searched around for an answer but while I have seen similar questions, it has not worked for my specific problem.

In my data set I am trying to use the `NA`'s as placeholders because I am going to return to them once I get part of my analysis done so therefore, I would like to be able to do all my calculations as if the `NA`'s weren't really there.

Here's my issue with an example data table

```
ROCA = c(1,3,6,2,1,NA,2,NA,1,NA,4,NA)
ROCA <- data.frame (ROCA=ROCA)       # converting it just because that is the format of my original data

#Now my function
exceedes <- function (L=NULL, R=NULL, na.rm = T)
 {
    if (is.null(L) | is.null(R)) {
        print ("mycols: invalid L,R.")
        return (NULL)               
    }
    test <-(mean(L, na.rm=TRUE)-R*sd(L,na.rm=TRUE))
  test1 <- sapply(L,function(x) if((x)> test){1} else {0})
  return (test1)
}
L=ROCA[,1]
R=.5
ROCA$newcolumn <- exceedes(L,R)
names(ROCA)[names(ROCA)=="newcolumn"]="Exceedes1"
```

I am getting the error:

```
Error in if ((x) > test) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

As you guys know, it is something wrong with the sapply function. Any ideas on how to ignore those `NA`'s? I would try `na.omit` if I could get it to insert all the `NA`'s right where they were before, but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Why not just add another if statement into the sapply function that returns NA if x is NA? Also, if you put `browser()` anywhere in your function, it will pause at that place when you run it the next time.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am not sure whether I did this right however, because I am still getting the same error. Here is my code   test1 <- sapply(L,function(x) if ((x) == NA) {NA} else 
  if((x)> test){1} else {0}
   )     and the error is now: Error in if ((x) == NA) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: You must use `is.na(x)` to check it. `x == NA` returns NA...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This statement is strange:

```
test1 <- sapply(L,function(x) if((x)> test){1} else {0})
```

Try:

```
test1 <- ifelse(is.na(L), NA, ifelse(L > test, 1, 0))
```

Comment: Can't thank both of you enough. Really appreciate the quick feedback!

Comment: I'm not sure if it's appropriate to ask a separate, but related question again here. Thanks to everyone's help I wanted to make one small tweak. Certain parts of my data has blanks, I want to specify that if two columns each have blanks, than columns 5 through 10 will have the value NA. The code that I have tried to use is this. I surely need to review my if statements. a<- if(a[,10]&a[,11]=="" is.na(a[,5:10])   I get Error: unexpected symbol in "a<- if(a[,10]&a[,11]=="" is.na"

Comment: 'if' is a control structure. You probably want 'ifelse' which returns a vector.

Comment: I think you need something like `a[a[,10]=="" & a[,11]=="",5:10] <- NA`.  `is.na` is for testing that a variable is NA, not for setting it to NA.

Answer (score 5):

There's no need for `sapply` and your anonymous function because `>` is already vectorized.

It also seems really odd to specify default argument values that are invalid.  My guess is that you're using that as a kludge instead of using the `missing` function.  It's also good practice to throw an error rather than return `NULL` because you would still have to try to catch when the function returns `NULL`.

```
exceedes <- function (L, R, na.rm=TRUE)
{
  if(missing(L) || missing(R)) {
    stop("L and R must be provided")
  }
  test <- mean(L,na.rm=TRUE)-R*sd(L,na.rm=TRUE)
  as.numeric(L > test)
}

ROCA <- data.frame(ROCA=c(1,3,6,2,1,NA,2,NA,1,NA,4,NA))
ROCA$Exceeds1 <- exceedes(ROCA[,1],0.5)
```

Comment: The advantage of using null is that it's always easy to explicitly pass in. In some situations generating "missing" arguments is a pain.

Comment: @hadley: I agree (that's how `plot.default` handles several arguments) but I was referring to this specific situation where `NULL` argument values are invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want NA:s in the result? That is, do you want the rows to line up?

seems like just returning `L > test` would work then. And adding the column can be simplified too (I suspect "Exeedes1" is in a variable somewhere).

```
exceedes <- function (L=NULL, R=NULL, na.rm = T)
 {
    if (is.null(L) | is.null(R)) {
        print ("mycols: invalid L,R.")
        return (NULL)               
    }
    test <-(mean(L, na.rm=TRUE)-R*sd(L,na.rm=TRUE))

    L > test
}
L=ROCA[,1]
R=.5
ROCA[["Exceedes1"]] <- exceedes(L,R)
```