# How to pass na.rm=TRUE to sapply when calculating median?

Tags: r, na, sapply, na.rm

I have created a dataframe "killers" with 3 variables. The data are numeric though there exist `NA` values throughout.

My goal is to calculate the mean on each of the 3 variables.

```
sapply(killers, function(x) median)
```

This returns:

```
$heartattack
function (x, na.rm = FALSE) 
UseMethod("median")
<bytecode: 0x103748108>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

I know that the `na.rm` argument is a means to ignore `NA` values. Since `na.rm = FALSE` exists in what was returned by R, one presumes that there is a way to set this to `TRUE` within the line of code above. I tried a few variations:

```
sapply(killers, na.rm=TRUE function(x) median)
sapply(killers, function(x) median, na.rm=TRUE)
sapply(killers, function(x) median(na.rm=TRUE))
```

I'm not sure if I'm close or if this is going to involve nesting functions, as per other similar (though ultimately not helpful in this instance that I can see) posts on the topic on SO. e.g. 
[How to pass na.rm as argument to tapply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172556/how-to-get-na-rm-into-function-for-tapply/14172864#14172864),
[Ignore NA's in sapply function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499905/ignore-nas-in-sapply-function)

Of course, I could just calculate the mean on each vector that was used to create killers, but surely if what I'm asking is possible then that is better.

Comment: `?sapply` says "...: optional arguments to 'FUN'." and there are examples of how to pass additional arguments to functions in the *Examples* section.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich not meant to be that offensive.

Comment: You asked `sapply` to return the function `median` and that's exactly what it did. Functions are objects. (What you did not do was tell it to return `median(x)`.)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Just do:

```
sapply(killers, median, na.rm = TRUE)
```

An alternative would be (based on your code)

```
sapply(killers, function(x) median(x, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Comment: very helful! `sapply(killers, function(x) median(x, na.rm=TRUE))` worked best for me